# LINQtoCSV Stream provided to read is either null, or does not support seek

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I am trying to use LINQtoCSV to parse out a CSV file into a list of objects and am receiving the error "Stream provided to read is either null, or does not support seek."

The error is happening at `foreach(StockQuote sq in stockQuotesStream)`

Below is the method that is throwing the error.  The .CSV file is being downloaded from the internet and is never stored to disk (only stored to StreamReader).

```
    public List<StockQuote> CreateStockQuotes(string symbol)
    {
        List<StockQuote> stockQuotes = new List<StockQuote>();

        CsvFileDescription inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
        {
            SeparatorChar = ',',
            FirstLineHasColumnNames = false
        };

        CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();

        IEnumerable<StockQuote> stockQuotesStream = cc.Read<StockQuote>(GetCsvData(symbol));

        foreach (StockQuote sq in stockQuotesStream)
        {
            stockQuotes.Add(sq);
        }

        return stockQuotes;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a MemoryStream first and then a StreamReader was the answer, but I went about it a little differently than mentioned.

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        using (MemoryStream download = new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData(url)))
        {
            using (StreamReader dataReader = new StreamReader(download, System.Text.Encoding.Default, true))
            {
                return dataReader;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

> The .CSV file is being downloaded from the internet and is never stored to disk (only stored to StreamReader).

Well presumably that's the problem. It's not quite clear what you mean by this, in that if you have wrapped a `StreamReader` around it, that's a pain in terms of the underlying stream - but you can't typically seek on a stream being downloaded from the net, and it sounds like the code you're using requires a seekable stream.

One simple option is to download the whole stream into a `MemoryStream` (use `Stream.CopyTo` if you're using .NET 4), then rewind the `MemoryStream` (set `Position` to 0) and pass *that* to the `Read` method.